# Omitting the creation of a temporary access path with DB2/400 when accessing DDS-defined tables with SQL

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I have two table definitions in DDS, compiled into *FILE objects and filled with data:

Kunpf:

```
A                                      UNIQUE
A          R KUNTBL
A            FIRMA         60A         ALWNULL
A            KUNR           5S 0B
A            KUNID          4S 0B
A          K KUNR
A          K KUNID
```

Kunsupf:

```
A          R KUNSUTBL
A            KUNID     R        B      REFFLD(KUNID KUN/KUNPF)
A
A            SUCHSTR       78A
A          K SUCHSTR
A          K KUNID
```

I'm using the following statement in interactive SQL (`STRSQL`):

```
SELECT DISTINCT FIRMA, KUNR FROM KUN/KUNPF
 LEFT JOIN KUN/KUNSUPF ON (KUNPF.KUNID = KUNSUPF.KUNID)
 WHERE SUCHSTR LIKE 'Freiburg%'
 ORDER BY FIRMA
 FOR READ ONLY
```

Everytime I execute this statement, I'm getting a considerable delay until the answer screen opens up. Beforehand a message is shown, stating that a temporary access path is being created.

**How can I find out which/how this temporary access path is created?** My goal is to have this access path made permanent so it doesn't need to be rebuilt with every invocation of this query.

I searched the net (especially the IBM site) but what I found out was mostly for DB2 on z/OS. The `F4`-Prompting facility in `STRSQL` doesn't provide help: I was searching for something like `EXPLAIN SELECT` from MySQL. The IBM *DB2 Advanced Functions and Administration* PDF states that there's a debug mode but it seems that it is only available from some (old) Windows tool I don't remember to have.

I'm utilizing V4R5, if this is relevant.

Comment: if you do a where clause on a field from a left joined file the file becomes joined so only matching records are displayed.

Comment: @danny117 Pardon me but I can't fit your comment into something helpful for the question above. Please elaborate.

Comment: In terms of wrkqry.  The query has changed from join type 2 to join type 1 because you have a "field from the left join file in the where clause" of a sql statement.  WHERE SUCHSTR LIKE 'Freiburg%'  field SUCHSTR is in the left join file kunspf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to see the access path on the green screen...

- strdbg
- strsql
- run your statement
- exit f3
- enddbg
- dspjoblog

  the access path messages are at the bottom of the log f10 f18 afaik

Comment: Thank you, that was incredibly helpful!

Answer (score 1):

v4r5???  That's like 20 years old...

For the IBM i, the "Run SQL Scripts" component of the old Client Access For Windows iSeries Navigator component and the new Access Client Solutions (ACS) contains Visual Explain (VE).

Luckily it seems though it was added to v4r5 
http://ibmsystemsmag.com/ibmi/administrator/db2/database-performance-tuning-with-visual-explain/

Just start iNav, right click on "Database" and select "Run SQL Scripts"

Paste your query there and click "Visual Explain" -->"Run and Explain"
(or the corresponding button)

**Optionally, in green screen.**
Do a STRDBG to enter debug mode, F12 to continue and then go into STRSQL.  The Db optimizer will then output additional messages into the joblog giving you more information about what it is doing..

Comment: I didn't see you had the optionally.

Comment: @danny117 how's that? :)

Comment: @Charles: Basic stuff (files, work management, READ/WRITE-Calls, etc.) is mostly the same since probably V1, so age isn't an argument for updating to me. Besides, V4R5 on a 150 runs without need for horribly expensive LICKEYs. This is the most important part, as I'm tinkering with AS/400 as a hobby. IBM failed for years to provide an equivalent to DEC's Hobbyist License for VMS (which you still could acquire today from HPE!). Besides, this hardware requires only about 100W of power. But thanks for your answer, though!

Comment: @PoC The issue with such old stuff is that IBM's documentation on the knowledge center only goes back to v5r3. That will make it difficult to find things for v4r5.

Comment: @jmarkmurphy: Good point. Fortunately, Astradyne.net has many of the old manuals available.